# Equivalence Selector

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know if there's an equivalence selector in jQuery? Of course `:contains` exist, but what if we want exact matches?

My workaround is to do

```
$('a').filter(function() {
   return $(this).text() == myVar;
}).addClass('highlight');
```

But I was hoping of a much easier method of doing `$('a:equals(' + myVar + ')').addClass('highlight')` instead.  Of course I could create the selector, but I'd have assumed something exists in the standard library.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be a pre-built selector for this but if I understand it correctly, you could register your own easily as `:contentEquals` or whatever.

[Here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) is an example of how somebody implemented a regex filter selector.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need your own custom selector:
There's a discussion about them here
[What useful custom jQuery selectors have you written?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940574/what-useful-custom-jquery-selectors-have-you-written)

Your custom selector might look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.extend($.expr[':'], { 
        myEquivalence: function(el) { 
            return ($(el).val() == myVar);
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Yup, I knew exactly this is what I was going to need as I had previously pointed out.  Good to see an example though, thanks very much!