# :nth-of-type() in jQuery / Sizzle?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, selectors-api

It surprised me that [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) (the selector engine jQuery uses) comes with a built-in `:nth-child()` selector, but lacks an `:nth-of-type()` selector.

To illustrate the difference between `:nth-child()` and `:nth-of-type()` and to illustrate the problem, consider [the following HTML document](http://jsbin.com/ezaya3/7):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>:nth-of-type() in Sizzle/jQuery?</title>
  <style>
   body p:nth-of-type(2n) { background: red; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>The following CSS is applied to this document:</p>
  <pre>body p:nth-of-type(2n) { background: red; }</pre>
  <p>This is paragraph #1.</p>
  <p>This is paragraph #2. (Should be matched.)</p>
  <p>This is paragraph #3.</p>
  <p>This is paragraph #4. (Should be matched.)</p>
  <div>This is not a paragraph, but a <code>div</code>.</div>
  <p>This is paragraph #5.</p>
  <p>This is paragraph #6. (Should be matched.)</p>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(function() {
    // The following should give every second paragraph (those that had red backgrounds already after the CSS was applied) an orange background.
    // $('body p:nth-of-type(2n)').css('background', 'orange');
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Since Sizzle uses the browser-native `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` methods if those are present (i.e. in browsers that already implement the [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/)), stuff like `$('body p:nth-child');` will of course work. It won’t work in older browsers though, because Sizzle has no fallback method for this selector.

Is it possible to easily add the `:nth-of-type()` selector to Sizzle, or to implement it in jQuery (by using [the built-in `:nth-child()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), perhaps)? A [custom selector with parameters](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/jquery-custom-selectors-with-parameters.html) would be nice.

Comment: Not sure, but won't `$('p:even')` give you what you're looking for? You already have the selector (`p`), so you just need to filter it.

Comment: @Kobi: It’s not that easy. The selector `p:nth-child(2n)` would match every second paragraph *in every parent element*. If there are two DIVs, both containing three paragraphs, the following paragraphs (in DOM order) would be matched by `p:nth-child(2n)`: #2, #5. See? It’s not just a matter of getting every `P` in the document and then filtering it down to every *mn*th elementh.
Yes, `$('p:even')` is an alias for `$('p:nth-child(2n)')`, but not for `$('p:nth-of-type(2n)')`. Also, I’m using `2n` in this example, but of course other variations should be possible as well.

Comment: Got it, and deleted my answer.

Comment: `$('body p:nth-of-type(n)').css('background', 'orange');` is working in firefox here on jQuery 1.4, are you asking how to implement this strictly for older browsers, e.g. implement only the fallback version?

Comment: Nick Craver, like I explained in my post, that’s because Firefox is one of the browsers with a native implementation of the Selectors API. Sizzle doesn’t know the `:nth-of-type()` selector, but Firefox’s `querySelectorAll()` does. That’s why it ‘works’ — but it’s not thanks to Sizzle. It would be good to have this in Sizzle because then it would work in **all** browsers.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on why $('body p:nth-child') does not work in older browsers? Because that's your only argument against using it, right?

Comment: littlegreen: `$('body p:nth-child')` works in every browser, because Sizzle has a built-in `:nth-child()` selector. So, if the browser doesn’t implement the Selectors API, Sizzle just uses that instead. The problem is Sizzle lacks an `:nth-of-type()` selector.

Comment: Wouldn't you know it, it wasn't implemented simply because [John Resig didn't think it was worth implementing](http://ejohn.org/blog/selectors-that-people-actually-use).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
/**
 * Return true to include current element
 * Return false to exclude current element
 */
$.expr[':']['nth-of-type'] = function(elem, i, match) {
    if (match[3].indexOf("n") === -1) return i + 1 == match[3];
    var parts = match[3].split("+");
    return (i + 1 - (parts[1] || 0)) % parseInt(parts[0], 10) === 0;
};
```

**[Test case](http://jsbin.com/eyaqa4/latest)** - (*check in IE or rename the selector*)

You can of course add **even *&* odd** too:

```
match[3] = match[3] == "even" ? "2n" : match[3] == "odd" ? "2n+1" : match[3];
```

​

Comment: Cool! This is what I was looking for; a short, clever, concise, solution. As you know, `:odd` and `:even` are already supported in jQuery, just not in the `:nth-of-type(odd)` / `:nth-of-type(even)` form, but it’s nice to have ’em in there as well for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Update: for even more selectors, see https://github.com/keithclark/JQuery-Extended-Selectors

Comment: Nice, but i just wanted to warn others about this solution always assuming a periodicity (n). I mean, filter like `:nth-of-type(2n)` and `:nth-of-type(2)` will be the same (when the latter should only be the 2nd element, instead of all the even elements).

Answer (score 4):

the jQuery plugin [moreSelectors](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/moreSelectors) has support for nth-of-type (and many other selectors). I suggest either using that, or simply implement a simple plugin that only implements the exact selectors you need. You should be able to copy-paste code from there.

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 1):

I can't pretend to know how nth-of-type is implemented, but jQuery does provide a mechanism by which you can create your own custom selector.

The following question deals with custom selectors, and may provide a useful insight to you

[What useful custom jQuery selectors have you written?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940574/what-useful-custom-jquery-selectors-have-you-written)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this… I should probably add that to my post.