# JavaScript/JQuery string replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex, css-selectors

I have the following string which is a CSS selector:

```
#downloads > ul > li:nth-of-type(1) > ul > li:nth-of-type(3) > a
```

This CSS selector works fine in FireFox, CHrome and Safari but IE 6 does not support the nth-of-type selector.  The CSS selectors I am working with are generated by Nokogiri and I can not change them.

Threw testing I have got the following working:

```
#downloads > ul > li:nth(0) > ul > li:nth(2) > a
```

Changing the nth selector to a plain nth and subtracting one from the nth value.  I have been trying to programmitcally with JS to convert a CSS selector from using nth-of-type to normal nth?  So after running it threw:

```
#downloads > ul > li:nth-of-type(1) > ul > li:nth-of-type(3) > a
```

Would become

```
#downloads > ul > li:nth(0) > ul > li:nth(2) > a
```

Cheers

Eef

Comment: See Emil Stenström's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093355/nth-of-type-in-jquery-sizzle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
var str = "#downloads > ul > li:nth-of-type(1) > ul > li:nth-of-type(3) > a";
str = str.replace(/:nth-of-type\(([0-9]+)\)/g, function(match, first) {
   return ":nth(" + (parseInt(first)-1) + ")";
});

alert(str); // -> #downloads > ul > li:nth(0) > ul > li:nth(2) > a
```

### [[See it in action](http://jsbin.com/iyani4/)]

​