# jQuery nth-of-type not working in IE7 or 8

Tags: jquery

I have implemented some jQuery to fake nth-of-type in IE7 and 8 using the following code:

```
$.expr[':']['nth-of-type'] = function(elem, i, match) {
    var parts = match[3].split("+");
    return (i + 1 - (parts[1] || 0)) % parseInt(parts[0], 10) === 0;
};
$("div>section.subcontent:nth-of-type(3)").addClass('nth-three');
$("div>section.subcontent:nth-of-type(4)").addClass('nth-four');
```

However it only works in Chrome and other browsers... Any ideas why? As the point of the JS is to rely on JS where CSS fails in IE compatibility.

Thanks

Comment: Try using this plugin (adds all the "type" selectors): https://github.com/keithclark/JQuery-Extended-Selectors

Comment: Same issue that classes are only added in browsers that already support the selector rather than actually adding to ones that don't

Comment: And what about the snippet here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093355/nth-of-type-in-jquery-sizzle? What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Using 1.6.4 and it's working in Chrome so it's more of an IE issue.

Comment: Well it's clear that it only works when the browser actually implements the selector, so the snippet probably doesn't work at all.

Comment: Have you added the [IE HTML5 enabling script](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/)? It could be that jQuery's working and adding the classes as expected, but the styles don't take effect because IE7/8 don't style the new elements without that script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression works just fine, even in IE7.

The problem is that IE (versions before 9) doesn´t handle HTML5 elements like `section` that well.

> **The section element is not a generic container element**. When an
>   element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for
>   scripting, **authors are encouraged to use the div element instead**. A
>   general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the
>   element’s contents would be listed explicitly in the document’s
>   outline.

From http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element

Replace the `section` elements with ordinary `div`s and you´ll see that there´s nothing wrong with your expression.

**UPDATE**

There´re fixes to this problem and one of them are to use this script to create one of each HTML5 element to make IE aware of them;

```
<script>
  for(var e,l='article aside footer header nav section time'.split(' ');e=l.pop();document.createElement(e))
</script>
```

You can read more about this [here](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-with-CSS-for-Safari,-Firefox,-Opera-and-IE.html) and [here](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/Simple-HTML5-Fix-for-IE.html).

Comment: Considering that IE doesn't even support the new HTNL5 elements (unless you use the `createElement` trick), I doubt that IE wouldn't style them, just because the specs say so.

Comment: That´s true. A bit tricky that other browsers allow these element to be styled though.

Comment: You're reading the specs wrong. It says, "When an element is needed **only** for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting". That's not the same as saying you can't style it at all.

Comment: @YiJiang You are absolutely right, my mistake. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses the sizzle selector engine to select DOM elements.

According to the sizzle.js docs ( https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Home ), the following selectors:

- :nth-of-type
- :nth-last-of-type
- :first-of-type
- :last-of-type
- :only-of-type

aren't supported by the library - the reasoning is here: http://ejohn.org/blog/selectors-that-people-actually-use/

So I can only surmise that where the browse itself does not implement the selector, jQuery does not patch it with some clever js.

A better solution might be to just run through the elements, giving them the appropriately numbered classname as you go - this would acheive the same effect with less fluff:

```
var c=1;
$('yourelems').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('child-'+c);
    c++; //yes that's a pun :)
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Are you sure you understand his question? He's not asking about jQuery support for `nth-of-type` - he's adding the selector himself using `jQuery.expr`, like so: http://www.ericmmartin.com/creating-a-custom-jquery-selector/

Comment: $('selector').each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass('child-' + i);
});

Comment: @YiJiang yes it seems I've misunderestimated the question - rather than delete it I'm going to leave it here as there are comments and the $.each solution is still valid.