# Add class to nth-child of parent which has particular class, with jquery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

This is best explained with a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hxsJx/

I want to add a class to the nth-children of an element, but only when those children have a particular class.  So in my example, only articles E and J should get the class of 'end'.

The nth-child selector seems to be ignoring the class selector, which is probably intended behaviour, but I just can't find a way around it.

Thanks for any pointers folks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is working as intended. Remember, the CSS `:nth-child` selector is one-based (it starts counting at one).

The `4n`th elements are `D` and `H`, which indeed have class `1`.

Your selector: `.articles article.1:nth-child(4n)`

HTML:

```
<section class="articles">          .articles
<article class="1 4">A</article>        :nth-child(1)
<article class="1 4">B</article>        :nth-child(2)
<article class="2 2">C</article>        :nth-child(3)
<article class="1">D</article>          :nth-child(4)  and  :nth-child(4n) and .1
<article class="1">E</article>          :nth-child(5)
<article class="3 2">F</article>        :nth-child(6)
<article class="1 4">G</article>        :nth-child(7)
<article class="1 2">H</article>        :nth-child(8)  and  :nth-child(4n) and .1
<article class="1 3 4">I</article>      :nth-child(9)
<article class="1 2 4">J</article>      :nth-child(10)
</section>
```

Comment: No, I don't think so.  Compare: http://jsfiddle.net/s2LrG/.  The nth-child selector is being ignored.

Comment: @Dan How is the `:nth-child` selector being ignored? Elements D and H are the 4n-th (4 and 8) child element with respect to their parent, and they both have class `1`. Did you confuse `:nth-child(4n)` with `:nth-child(4n-1)`: http://jsfiddle.net/s2LrG/1/?

Comment: Maybe there's confusion in the question...  What I'm trying to do with that example is only give a class of 'end' to the nth-children which have a class of '1'.  So only articles A, B, D, E, G, H, I and J have the class of '1' so I'm wanting to apply the class to every 4th item of this selection.  E and J (the 4th and 8th items which have the class of '1') should be the ones which end up with the class 'end'.

Comment: I think I get how it works now, thanks to your responses, but it's not how I expected it to work and I'm struggling to do what I want it to.  I want to get all articles with a class of '1' and THEN apply a class of 'end' to every nth-child of that selection.  Can you see where I'm coming from?  Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the `:nth-child` selector. It is a true **index-of-child selector**. jQuery/Sizzle doesn't support such dynamic type selectors. You can reduce select such childs, for example using: `$('.articles article.1').filter(function(i){return i%4===0;})`

Comment: @Dan **[This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4761510)** provides an extension to jQuery's set of selectors, which enables the [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector for jQuery.

Comment: The nth-of-type selector is what I need.  Thanks!  Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/ScxCc/

Answer (score 0):

Try Lettering.js  http://letteringjs.com/

Comment: What's the relevance with this question?

Comment: It is a jQuery plugin to style individual characters.

Answer (score 0):

No, Rob W is right.

```
//$('.articles article').removeClass('end');
$('.articles article.1:nth-child(4n)').addClass('end');​
```

Makes D and H the target, but if you set it to

```
//$('.articles article').removeClass('end');
$('.articles article.1:nth-child(5n)').addClass('end');​
```

E and J become the target.

EDIT: The 4th Child is D and H. D is equal to 4 and H is equal to 8.

```
1 = A
2 = B
3 = C
4 = D
```

etc, you're getting your numbers mixed up. E and J are the 5th and 10th children, respectively.

Comment: Yep, I can see that this is probably how it's supposed to be (I've not unearthed a great big bug in jQuery :)) but I'm struggling to get across what I'm actually wanting to do.  I essentially want to do this in two parts:  First, get all articles which have a class of '1'.  Then apply a class of 'end' to every 4th item of that particular selection.  What it's doing at the moment is taking the nth-child and adding the class if it has a class of '1'.  What I want to do is only take the articles with a class of '1' and THEN apply a class of 'end' to every nth item of THAT selection.

Comment: The numbers are right - totally get that.  The issue is that in my example, 'C' doesn't have a class of '1' so it shouldn't (at least I don't want it to) count in the nth-child selection.  I only want to include the articles which have a class of '1' in the initial selection, then do an nth-child filter on just those articles.