# Nth-of-type alternative for IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, jquery-selectors

I have rows of product divs. Need to add a clear div after every fourth item. 4 to a row.

I'm using `jQuery('.product:nth-of-type(4n+2)').after("<div class='clear'></div>");` right now, but that doesn't support IE8. And since we're using jQuery, selectivizrs fix won't work in this case.

I've also tried

```
            addDynamicRow = function() {
            var divs = $(".product-section > .product");
            for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=4) {
              divs.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll("<div class='row'></div>");
            }  

            $('.row').after("<div class='clear'></div>")   
        }

        addDynamicRow();
```

But that grabs all of the product divs in the other product-section wrappers as well and puts them into groups of four regardless of where they're at.

Anyone know a work-a-round? I havn't been able to find a solution.

Thanks!

**1/15/13 Update:** jQuery 1.9 now supports the following CSS3 selectors across all browsers, all the way back to IE6: :nth-last-child, :nth-of-type, :nth-last-of-type, :first-of-type, :last-of-type, :only-of-type, :target, :root, and :lang.

Comment: I took a look, it was a little above my cognitive level. I don't understand the solution.

Comment: see [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093355/nth-of-type-in-jquery-sizzle)

Comment: Is that an extension of the jQuery core? O_o

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall It's an extension to jQuery's selector engine. Note: The accepted answer on the duplicate includes a link to https://github.com/keithclark/JQuery-Extended-Selectors. Even dummies should be able to read the concise documentation, and understand the simple example.

Comment: That plugin worked. Have it in a conditional and am following on github. Thanks Rob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ended up using https://github.com/keithclark/JQuery-Extended-Selectors in an IE conditional statement. It's working now.

Comment: So somebody else answered your question, but you posted a duplicate then accepted your own answer?

Comment: The guy posted that answer 5 months after I posted this one. Check the dates...

Comment: Indeed... my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

[JQuery-Extended-Selectors](https://github.com/keithclark/JQuery-Extended-Selectors)

It will solve your problem, it helps all css3 selector classes.

Comment: Yep, that's what I used.

Answer (score 1):

The [`.filter` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) might be abused to work around that missing CSS3-support of jQuery:

```
jQuery('.product').filter(function(i){return i%4==2;})
```

although that emulates `nth-child`, not `nth-of-type`, and only in the current set of selected elements instead of being based on their DOM position.

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to use a javascript solution, then the best one I know of is [Selectivz](http://selectivizr.com/). It adds support to IE for a whole bunch of advanced CSS selectors.

It does this using any one of several libraries, including jQuery. However it's worth noting from their home page that `nth-of-type` is mentioned as not being supported when used in conjunction with jQuery. It does work with MooTools, Prototype, and other libraries though. I don't know why it has a problem with jQuery specifically.

If that doesn't work for you, an older script called [IE9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) might help you. This is a big hack that tries to add a whole bunch of missing functionality into older versions of IE, including `nth-of-type` and other CSS selectors. It also tries to fix a whole bunch of IE bugs.

Either of these libraries may work for you, and allow you to use advanced CSS selectors without worrying about old versions of IE. Give them a go.

Comment: I can't use selectivzr for the aforementioned purpose. But I tried implementing the conditional for ie9.js. The conditional is before my domReady.js file but I'm still getting error. SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: nth-of-type 
jquery-1.7.2.min.js, line 3 character 15260

Comment: IE9.js won't affect jQuery's ability to support `nth-of-type`. It would only work for selectors in your actual stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to load a full library of selectors, check this out: https://gist.github.com/oliverbenns/6740630