# nth-child selecting wrong element

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

For this particular site, when I utilize nth-child via CSS or jQuery, the 'nth-child' selector is capturing the wrong element. I'm getting one child before the selector that I'm calling:

```
.home article:nth-child(3) {} //captures 2nd child
```

This seems to be capturing the second child instead. If I attempt:

```
.home article:nth-child(1) {} //captures nothing
```

This captures no elements. In jQuery, it shows up as an empty array. Here's the dev site that I'm working on. Thank you.

http://heilbrice.designliftoff.com/

Comment: hmm.. Not sure why that is happening. Have you tried $('.home article').eq(1); ?

Comment: Can you reproduce this is a JSFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/nBfdX/ seems to be working in Safari. What browser are you testing in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your site, you have a clearfix `div` that's the first child of its parent element within your container, so your first `article` is really the *second* child, not the first:

```
<div class="row-main clearfix">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>  <!-- .row-main.clearfix > :nth-child(1) -->

    <article id="post-" class=""> <!-- .row-main.clearfix > :nth-child(2) -->
```

In CSS, you can use `:nth-of-type()` instead to reach the third `article` element:

```
/* Select the 3rd article in its parent within .home */
.home article:nth-of-type(3) {}
```

Oddly enough, [jQuery does not support `:nth-of-type()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093355/nth-of-type-in-jquery-sizzle), so for a cross-browser solution you have to opt with [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector) with a zero-based index:

```
// Select the 3rd article within .home
$('.home article:eq(2)')
```

Comment: Aha. Thank you for pointing out that the empty div was doing that. I removed said div and will keep this in mind. Thanks.

Comment: :eq() fixed an issue with my app running on Safari / iPad with iOS 8.2. I had been using :nth-child() which worked with iOS 8.1 and all other major browsers.
The :nth-child(2) selector returned a jQuery object with length = 0 when there were in fact 2 elements.

Comment: @normc: Wow, what a curious case. I hope it gets fixed before GM.