# Select label by nth-of-type

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

In this markup, I need to replace the label text "E-mail" with "User Name". I only have access via jQuery.

```
    <div class="foo" style="border:1px solid #444">
          <span class="field-with-fancyplaceholder">
          <label class="placeholder" for="pseudonym_session_unique_id" style="font-size: 13px;">
          <span>Email</span>
          </label>
          <input id="pseudonym_session_unique_id" class="text" type="text" size="30" name="pseudonym_session[unique_id]">
</span>
          <span class="field-with-fancyplaceholder">
          <label class="placeholder" for="pseudonym_session_password" style="font-size: 13px;">
          <span>Password</span>
          </label>
          <input id="pseudonym_session_password" class="text" type="password" size="30" name="pseudonym_session[password]">
          </span>
        </div>
```

When I try this

```
$('label:nth-of-type(1)').addClass('bar');  
$('.bar span').text('user name'); 
// because $('label:nth-of-type(1) span') doesn't work
```

both labels get selected and both spans say "user name." How can I get just the first one?

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbweb/j6nfv/).

Comment: Be careful, as jQuery doesn't actually support `:nth-of-type()`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745274/what-css3-selectors-does-jquery-really-support-e-g-nth-last-child and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093355/nth-of-type-in-jquery-sizzle Although it works in your case, it only does because jQuery is letting the browser handle the selection. Not that this has anything to do with the question itself, but just thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the `:contains` selector:

```
$('.foo label span:contains("Email")').text('user name');
```

Answer (score 4):

The labels don't have the same parent element, and `:nth-of-type` is based on siblings (elements with the same parent).

Note: `:nth-of-type` is not being implemented by jQuery in browsers that don't natively support it, meaning it won't work in IE6 7 or 8.

Answer (score 3):

You can more reliably select the correct element by more specific attributes:

```
$("[for=pseudonym_session_unique_id] > span").text("user name");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`:eq`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_eq.asp).

```
$('label:eq(0) span').text('user name');​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enLag/).