# Selecting all the divs with png background-image

Tags: jquery, html, png, jquery-selectors

How can I select in jQuery all the `div`s that have `background-image: url(somepath/somename.png)` in their style?

Comment: It seems to me that the only method is using foreach and checking style values...

Comment: @Kirzilla: Then I suggest you read the answers below, each one of them are valid methods :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a jQuery selector, but this might work:

```
$('div').each( function() {
    if ( $(this).css('background-image') == 'url("image.png")' ) {
        // do something here
    }
});
```

However, a more efficient method would be to make sure you only have a single class that uses that background image, then simply select `$('.bgClass')`

Comment: The problem is i have no access to the code generating the element. It's a weather web part and background-image address changes all the time. The div has no class. These points lead me to this question.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a custom selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.extend($.expr[':'], { 
        hasMyImage: function(el) { 
            return ($(el).css('background-image') == "Url('somepath/somename.png')");
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Then to select:

```
$("div:hasMyImage");
```

Comment: A regexp would be required for a proper cross-browser match on `background-image`.  Some browsers return the value with string identifiers (`'`), some don't.  The case of `url()` could be different too.

Comment: +1 this is great, didn't know you could define new selectors .. this will come in handy

Answer (score 1):

Use the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function:

```
var matches = $("div").filter(function() 
{      
    return ($(this).css("background-image") == "url('somepath/somename.png')");
});
```