# val() vs. text() for textarea

Tags: jquery, forms, textarea

I am using jQuery, and wondering if I should use val() or text() (or another method) to read and update the content of a textarea.

I have tried both and I've had issues with both. When I use text() to update textarea, line breaks (\n) don't work. When I use val() to retrieve the textarea content, the text gets truncated if it's too long.

Comment: what does it mean line breaks don't work?

Comment: @kaz: the text stays on the same line.

Comment: And what do you mean by "text gets truncated" - in the debug output of the console? In the return value itself? Would be easier if you provided a jsfiddle...

Comment: @Connum: in the return value. Trying jsfiddle right now...

Comment: I got here by google'ing for truncated textarea text. I fixed my problem by adding a couple of \n\n to the end of the .val(). Weird but it worked.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

The best way to set/get the value of a textarea is the `.val()`, `.value` method.

`.text()` internally uses the `.textContent` (or `.innerText` for IE) method to get the contents of a `<textarea>`. The following test cases illustrate how `text()` and `.val()` relate to each other:

```
var t = '<textarea>';
console.log($(t).text('test').val());             // Prints test
console.log($(t).val('too').text('test').val());  // Prints too
console.log($(t).val('too').text());              // Prints nothing
console.log($(t).text('test').val('too').val());  // Prints too

console.log($(t).text('test').val('too').text()); // Prints test
```

The `value` *property*, used by `.val()` always shows the current visible value, whereas `text()`'s return value can be wrong.

Comment: thx, trying this right now. I am currently unable to replicate the issue I had with val() and truncation. Maybe I got the wrong suspect...

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the examples. Apparently that was my issue, I wrote with text() and read with val().

Comment: Changing the value of a textarea using `text()` does NOT work anymore after manually changing anything in it (e.g. adding a character)

Answer (score 15):

`.val()` always works with `textarea` elements.

`.text()` works sometimes and fails other times! It's not reliable (tested in Chrome 33)

What's best is that `.val()` works seamlessly with other form elements too (like `input`) whereas `.text()` fails.