# textarea value doesn't work

Tags: ajax

I tried $('#tresc_area').val() but it didn't work (don't know why). Inputs are correctly sending the information, but textarea has problem with it. Please help me.

```
<form method="post">
    <input class="input" type="text" name="do_kogo" id="odbiorca" size="25" value="<?php print $odbiorca; ?>" />
    <input class="input" id="temat" type="text" name="temat" size="25" value="<?php print $temat; ?>"/>
    <textarea id="tresc_area" cols="45" rows="10" ></textarea>
    <input onclick="Check()" id="send_submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>​
```

and here is the ajax. when i enter tresc: "content" then it correctly sends "content" but when i try to enter there tresc.value which is before declared as we can see it has a problems, even if i declare there "$('#tresc_area').val()" any propositions? please help me

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

var odbiorca = document.getElementById("odbiorca");
var temat = document.getElementById("temat");
var tresc = document.getElementById("tresc_area");

function Check() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "send_prv_msg.php",
        data: {
            do_kogo: odbiorca.value,
            temat: temat.value,
            tresc: tresc.value
        },
        success: function(odp) {
            $("p#error_box").html(odp);
        }
    });

}​

</script>
```

tresc: tresc.value <-- it doesn't work. somebody know how to make it work? please

Comment: Are you using some kind of asynchronous wrapper like `$(document).ready()` to make sure that your form elements are referenced after they become available in the DOM tree?

Comment: use `$('#tresc_area').text()`

Comment: how to use tresc.text()?

Comment: i tried to use $(document).ready() but it didn't change anything so i deleted it

Comment: @Qoop There are reasons why `text()` should be avoided in favor of `val()` or plain JavaScript `value` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854288/val-vs-text-for-textarea


@Michael
You have to use asynchronous wrappers if you are defining JavaScript code above elements which should be manipulated. Otherwise chances are your code will be referencing non-existent nodes inside the DOM tree.

Comment: tresc: $('#tresc_area').text() doesn't work ;/

Comment: @holodoc. I did not know that. I stand corrected.

Comment: so... anybody has an idea how can I make it work?

Comment: so.. have you tried `tresc: $('#tresc_area').val()`?

Comment: Is this script placed before or after the elements you're referencing?

Comment: this script is placed after the form

Comment: mike robinsons answer didnt work ;/ i get info that the content need to be entered

Comment: @Kosta
I changed onclick="Check()" to onclick="Check(); return false;". It is alert and it is different than my need.

Comment: @Michael please comment on answers, not here on question. Add `return false;` as a last statement inside `Check` function.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/AAb00q35
this is the php file. maybe somebody will see problem there because i dont know whats going on ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_comment_chk() {
    var ChkVars = {
        additional_register_mail_chk: 'Registered Mail $3.20 per parcel \n',
        additional_insurance_chk: 'Insurance $1.50 for every $100 of merchandise. \n',
        additional_international_chk: 'Registered Mail and insurance generally starts at $25 even for large letters, plus the cost of the postage. Please ask us for a quote.  \n'
    }

    var additonal = 'Additional Option: ';
    var mytextbox = document.getElementById('confirm_comment');
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    mytextbox.value = '';
    mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value.replace(additonal  + ChkVars[this.name], "");
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if(inputs[i].type === "checkbox") {
            inputs[i].onchange = function(){

                $('input[name*=\'additional\']:checked').each(function(){
                    mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + additonal  + ChkVars[this.name];
                });

                /*if(this.checked){
                    mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + additonal  + ChkVars[this.name];
                } else {
                    mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value.replace(additonal  + ChkVars[this.name], ""); 
                }*/
            }
        }  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery anyway, might as well take advantage of it's DOM selectors.

```
function Check() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "send_prv_msg.php",
        data: {
            do_kogo: $("#odbiorca").val(),
            temat: $("#temat").val(),
            tresc: $("#tresc").val()
        },
        success: function(odp) {
            $("p#error_box").html(odp);
        }
    });

}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple js fiddle how to read value from your text field: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jeWBm/). Enter any text to textarea and hit `Send` button.
Remember to add `return false;` at the end of your Check function, so form is not submitted.

Comment: I think the problem is in your form declaration. When you click the `Send` button, function `Check` is executed but since `Send` button is declared as submit button, the form is still submitted. Since you don't have `name` attribute on your textarea, its value is not submitted. Ether add attribute `name="tresc"` to textarea tag or change send from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and try again.