# Dumping textarea content into JS Alert?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, tinymce, alert

So, I have a form using TinyMCE editor and for debugging purposes I'd like to have the content of the textarea dumped into a simple JS alert box on submit:

```
<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:50%"></textarea>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Do you have an idea how this can me achieved?
Thanks a ton!
G

Comment: please use `console.log()` and see your text in FireBug or Chromes Element Inspector

Comment: @Kyslik Sometimes it's useful to use `alert()` instead of `console.log()`, especial in this case, when the value is needed just before submit...

Comment: seconded. Don't use alert, use the consonle, that's what it for. Unless you need to interrupt all execution on your page, with a throwaway label that you can't inspect, don't use `alert`.

Comment: I use `alert()` while "crafting" the script so I know right away if something is calling something, but for debugging I strictly use `console.log()`, note that `console.log()` does not [work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5473193/1564365) in IE 7-

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines in raw JavaScript.  As others have said, `console.log` is really helpful for debugging - but if you *want* an alert...

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

input.addEventListener("click", 
                       function (event) {
                           event.preventDefault(); // Remove this to make the event actually go through.
                           var textBox = document.getElementsByName("content")[0];
                           alert(textBox.value);
                       }, 
                       false);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/53eYv/)

Comment: Thanks Eric - I tried this and if I add the script after the form I get an empty alert box.The same script added before the form gives me a: `code`TypeError: input is undefined
 

input.addEventListener("click",

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <textarea name="content" class="textarea-test" style="width:50%"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="test-link">click me</a>
</form>

$(document).on("click", "test-link", function () {
     console.log($(".textarea-test").val());
});
```

do not forget about loading jQuery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and also check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8854317/1564365).