# How remove content textarea after adding content ? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea with select list.
My select list add new content on the textarea.
But if I begin to write on the textarea and after I add content with my select list, I don't know how can I remove the first content and then putt the new content from my select list.

Html :

```
<div id="selectmodelediv">
        <select>
         <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1111">test1</option>
        <option value="222">test2</option>
        </select><br />

        <textarea id="targetText" name="targetText" class="champ_tel_txtarea" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>

      </div>
```

Jquery :

```
$('select').change(function () {
$('#targetText').text(''); // I try to clear my textarea before to add content
$('#targetText').append($('#selectmodelediv select').val()) // add new content from select list

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on both sides, as it supports `<textarea>` elements:

```
$("#targetText").val($("#selectmodelediv select").val());
```

Answer (score 1):

append is used to add some html to the selected element, what you need to do is -

```
$('select').change(function () {
$('#targetText').val($("#selectmodelediv select").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
$('#targetText').val($('#selectmodelediv select').val())
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ccTLS/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').change(function () {
    $('#targetText').val($(this).val()) // add new content from select list
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q5ypQ/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    $('#targetText').val($('#targetText').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use .val() function to get/set the textarea field. According to this answer [val() vs. text() for textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854288/val-vs-text-for-textarea) text() sometimes can do "unexpected" things if you think on it as val().

Try the following:

```
$('#targetText').val($('#selectmodelediv select').val())
```