# char limit issue on IE 10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am using this function to limit characters in a `textarea`.  Works well on all browsers minus `IE10` (refuse to test on anything lower). 
This part `$(target).text(num - len);` places the actual number into the textarea,  not the limit. 
Can anyone point to a fix for IE10 please,  im just not that versed with microsoft products.  thank you

```
function countChar(val, target, num){
    var len = val.value.length;
    if (len >= num) {
            val.value = val.value.substring(0, num);
            $(target).text(0);
    }else {
            $(target).text(num - len);
    }

};
```

here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/uFDhZ/

on fiddle IE is not responding to the limit

**edit**  reversing order seems to have fixed it:

```
$(target).text(0);
val.value = val.value.substring(0, num);
```

Comment: Which IE version doesn't work?

Comment: @DamianFrizzi updated my question,  IE 10 is what im testing on

Comment: They said IE10 in their question I believe.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with ALL of your code?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the call to .text()? You are setting the characters remaining into the textarea?? Why are you doing that?

Comment: see [more explanation of text vs. val](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854288/val-vs-text-for-textarea)

Comment: @jalynn2 limiting text into the area.  if user goes over the max amount then nothing new can be added

Comment: Setting the number into `text()` doesn't do that. If it did, you wouldn't see the extra number appear and disappear as you type it in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to test it with IE but try this:

```
$('#myTxtArea').on('keyup propertychange', function(){
   countChar(this, '#myTxtArea', 10);
});
```

**EDIT**

I'm not sure why it's not working but I guess the event handler isn't recognized by IE for some reasons.

Could you try if the following works for you?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uFDhZ/4/)

```
$('#myTxtArea').on('keypress', function(e){

    e = e || window.event;

    var tval = $('#myTxtArea').val(),
        tlength = tval.length,
        set = 10,
        remain = parseInt(set - tlength);

        $('p').text(remain);

        if (remain <= 0 && e.which !== 0 && e.charCode !== 0) {
            $('textarea').val((tval).substring(0, tlength - 1))
        }
});
```

Comment: that didnt change anything

Comment: Im wondering if fiddle has issues on IE because im getting the same result, nothing changed.  will make an actual html/js page to test