# JQuery .html() and .text() returning empty values in Production

Tags: jquery, html

I have a textarea with an id of posttext.

I am trying to get the values of the textarea, but .html() and .text() always returns null in Production. But .val() returns the correct value. I am using IIS as the web server.

```
alert($("#posttext").html());    // returns empty
alert($("#posttext").val());     //returns the correct values
alert($("#posttext").text());    // returns empty
```

The code works fine when i run it locally, so is there any settings that is messed up in production ? Any way to debug ? Since its an ajax loaded form, i cannot see the textarea in view source.

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eVmQ9/4/ try this jsfiddle, replace html with val and it works. I have no clue why its working locally in my box.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854288/val-vs-text-for-textarea

Comment: thanks for the link, i guess i will use .val()

Comment: If its been resolved accept the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In jQuery, you use `.val()` to access the contents of a textarea.  That's how jQuery works.  You don't use `.html()` or `.text()`.  Your solution seems simple enough.  Just use `.val()`.

`.html()` and `.text()` return to you the values that were in the original HTML which is the initial value for the textarea, NOT the currently typed value.

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zV5zM/

Comment: Does .val() from a textarea  retains all the line break, line spacing etc, exactly the way the user entered ? I am using this textarea as a comment box.

Comment: @user636525 -yes it retains what was typed.  That is it's purpose.

Comment: @jfriend00 then what is the correct way to get the innerhtml of a div.id if it was updated dynamically later?

Answer (score 2):

It is not about local environment or production environment.

**Problem is this**: `html()` will always give you initial values and `val()` will give you the actual value present/written in textarea. See this [Jsbin Demo](http://jsbin.com/ubUTUME/1/edit?js,console,output)

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="ta"> This is html of textarea </textarea>
```

**JS**

```
var $t = $('#ta');
console.log($t.html());

$t.val('New html content of textarea');

console.log($t.html()); //  This is html of textarea
console.log($t.text()); //  This is html of textarea
console.log($t.val()); // New html content of textarea
```

Answer (score 1):

`.html()` & `.text()` will only give you the result that you added while coding.

**For example :** I added text between text area as : `<textarea name ="editor" id="editBox" rows="5" cols="2">aeflljn</textarea>` while coding.

So it will show : `aeflljn`.It will not alert changes that you make in the textbox.

<kbd>[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eVmQ9/9/)</kbd>

### So the only way to get correct value is to use `.val()`