# How to output a variable in Javascript to a textarea in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have got a variable in javascript called 'signature'

```
var signature;

//(Data is here)

document.write(signature)
```

In HTML, I have the following:

```js
<div id="siggen">
<textarea id="content" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
```

What i want is when i click generate button the variable signature appers in text area. Can anyone help?

Comment: following code html:

div id="siggen"> 
        <textarea id="content" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
   </div>

Comment: Please be more clear when you ask something

Comment: `document.getElementById('content').value = signature`

Comment: replace the `document.write(signature)` with the snippet in the comment here above ( from Marimuthu)

Comment: Either of the answers solves your problem. One uses jquery, the other doesn't.

Comment: its when i click button generate i want the variable signature to appear in text area, how do i do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need like:

```js
var signature = "Hello";
function addVal(){


    document.getElementById('content').value = signature
}
```

```html
<div id="siggen">
<textarea id="content" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
 <button id="btnClick" onclick="addVal()">Click</button>
```

Comment: its when i click button generate i want the variable signature to appear in text area, how do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery :

```
$("#content").val(signature)
```

See [val-vs-text-for-textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854288/val-vs-text-for-textarea)

Comment: its when i click button generate i want the variable signature to appear in text area, how do i do this?

Comment: $("#btnId").click(function() { $("#content").val(signature) })

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear but I assume you want to do something like this.

First in your html add a textarea and a button with these properties. Use disabled only if you want to make the text area disabled.

```html
<textarea disabled id="displaytext"></textarea>
<button  onclick="buttonFunction()">Click !</button>
```

Now in your javascript file, write the buttonFunction() to display the value in signature variable in the text area.

```js
var signature = "This is the content to display";

function buttonFunction() {
  document.getElementById("displaytext").innerHTML = signature;
}
```

This is the result. The text will be displayed when you click the button.
[image: output]