# Not getting text area text after button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some contend in textarea ..When I alert it give correct contend .But when I append in "hello" text in text contend area .and get contend on button click it does not give updated contend why ? it should show with "hello" contend.It show previous contend why ?

here is code
https://jsfiddle.net/4oa1q9qe/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert($("#test").html())   


 $("#btn").click(function(){
      alert($("#test").html())   
 })


})
```

- Add "hello" in text area and get get the contend it gives same contend why as previous ?

Comment: Please don't link to code, everything needed to understand the problem and desired result should be contained in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Use `val()` option to get the text value of input or textarea elements

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert($("#test").val())  

 $("#btn").click(function(){
      alert($("#test").val())   
 })
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4oa1q9qe/1/)

Comment: but @nagpal it fail When I need html contend ?

Comment: @user944513 That's not the purpose of `textarea` to contain HTML. I Think `textarea` tag name is quite explicit regarding it

Answer (score 2):

use `$("#test").val()` instead of `$("#test").html()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert($("#test").val())   
 
 
 $("#btn").click(function(){
      alert($("#test").val())   
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="test">
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies. 
</textarea>
<button id="btn">btn</button>
```

Comment: for html contend it fail  why ?

Answer (score 1):

> It show previous contend why ?

The inner content of the `<textarea>` element, e.g. `foo` in

```
<textarea>foo</textarea>
```

is used as the **default value**. Changing the **value** of the textarea does *not* change its inner content, it only changes the `value` *property*. Hence when you use `.html()`, you get the value that is present in the original HTML.

As already mentioned, use [**`.val()`**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the current value. See also [val() vs. text() for textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8854288/218196) .

Answer (score 1):

use `.val()` instead of `.html()`

`.val()` returns or sets the value of a `<textarea>` or `<input>`. It has *no* effect on anything else.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  alert($("textarea").val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<button>Show data</button>
```