# Why I can't retrieve the text inserted into a textarea tag using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I am pretty new in JavaScript and jQuery and I have the following problem.

Into a page I have the following textarea having `id="notaCorrente"`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="comment">Inserire una nota:</label>
    <textarea id="notaCorrente" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
```

in which the user can insert some text.

I don't want to submit this textarea into a form (there is not a form) but I want to retrieve the inserted value using jQuery (because then I have to perform an AJAX call using the retrieved text instead the post submit).

So I have do in this way:

```
function rimettiInLavorazioneProgetto() {
    alert("INTO rimettiInLavorazioneProgetto()");
    
    var testoNotaCorrente = $('#notaCorrente').text();
    
    alert("NOTA CORRENTE: " + testoNotaCorrente);
}
```

As you can see I try to retrieve the text inside the object having `id="notaCorrente"` but it can't work. I enter into the method but when print the second alert the retrieved text is always empty also if I have inserted some text into my textarea.

Why? What am I missing?

Comment: Use `val()`, not `text()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** not  **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** , because it will not return correct value sometimes. For more visit **[val() vs. text() for textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854288/val-vs-text-for-textarea)**

```
function rimettiInLavorazioneProgetto() {
    alert("INTO rimettiInLavorazioneProgetto()");    
    var testoNotaCorrente = $('#notaCorrente').val();    
    alert("NOTA CORRENTE: " + testoNotaCorrente);
}
```

Comment: Ok it wors but why? Why val extract the content of the textarea but text() not?

Comment: @AndreaNobili : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854288/val-vs-text-for-textarea