# Unable to append space to textarea content

Tags: javascript, jquery

This one is a strange one and I simply cannot get my head around it. We are trying to append space to a textarea content using the following jquery,

```
var checkThis ='help';
$('#msg').val(checkThis+' ');
$('#msg').focus();
```

But when we focus on the text area we can see that the space is not added. Also, the cursor doesn't focus automatically.

I am not able to figure out if there is any other script in the code doing this. This code is actually a large piece of maintenance code, is there anyway I can find what function may be trimming the text?

Comment: Are you including jQuery correctly? Any errors in the console? This works: https://jsfiddle.net/y9hvc0k3/

Comment: Can you set up a non-working example, cause it sure seems like it works -> http://jsfiddle.net/g850adqw/

Comment: "I am not able to figure out if there is any other script in the code doing this." - and you think someone else who hasn't seen the code would be able to?  One thought - is Angular involved at all - as ng-model auto-trims leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: Actually this code is a piece of maintenance code that am looking at and it's huge.. i am almost sure that some other piece of code is causing this, but cannot search in the mess. Anyway i can reach where the trim might be happening?

Comment: Attach a change handler, perhaps?

Comment: You can try text() instead of val() if its just about a quickfix. Some info about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854288/val-vs-text-for-textarea
`$('#msg').text(checkThis+' ').focus();`
Why this thing is not focusing, no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#msg').append(checkThis+'&nbsp;').focus();
```