# How to prevent truncaton of text while posting data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using $.post for posting data. I have one text area where user can enter any data. sometime enters html tags. when I saw on browser console before posting data. I can see whole text , but on server side I am only able to get some data.means some of the data gets truncated, I think this is happens when he enters html tags.how to prevent this?

```
$("#iNote").val()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854288/val-vs-text-for-textarea

Comment: The link @mkaatman posted is all you need. `val()` itself truncates. If you want the full contents, you need to use either `text()` or `html()` with a textarea. If you expect HTML and want to allow it, then use `html()`.

Comment: @skiskd $("#iNote").val() is jquery and its on client. Are you getting turncated values in $("#iNote").val()?