# Conflict use text() and val() methods at one time with reset button form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form and set values of some elements (such as `div`, `input`,...) with postfix `_holder` id.

I know for set value of form input elements must be use `val()` method.
And also I know for set value for another elements such as `span` and `div` must use `text()` method.

So I write this code:

```
<form id="myform">
    <span id="title_holder">###</span>
    <div id="description_holder">###</div>
    <input type="text" value="###" id="id_holder">
    <textarea id="others_holder">###</textarea>
    <input type="reset">
</form>

<script>
var values = {
    'title': '111',
    'description': '222',
    'id': '333',
    'others': '444',
};

$.each(values, function(key, value) {
    elementId = $('#' + key + '_holder');
    if (elementId.length > 0) {
        elementId
            .text(value) //for div and span elements
            .val(value); //for input and textarea elements
    }
});
</script>
```

See Online: https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/s13u699u/

I'm not sure for correction of use `text()` and `val()` at one time. But now all things works well.

But I have problem with reset form. The reset button just reset `input` box and don't work for `textarea`. (Of course I do not expect `span`, `div` to work on.)

If I remove `.text(value)` in code, reset button works well, But `span`, `div` don't get values.

My self thinks maybe need to check element before use `text()` or `val()` methods. but I'm not sure, and so I don't know how can check type element is an input form, See:

```
$.each(values, function(key, value) {
    elementId = $('#' + key + '_holder');
    if (elementId.length > 0) {
        //IF type of elementId is input form such as input, textarea,...
        elementId.val(value); //for input and textarea elements
        //ELSE normal html elements such as span, div,...
        elementId.text(value); //for div and span elements
    }
});
```

See Online: https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/s13u699u/1/

What is your suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854288/val-vs-text-for-textarea this may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use [**`.is`**](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method with [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector

*Check the current matched set of elements against a `selector, element, or jQuery object` and return `true` if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.*

```js
var values = {
  'title': '111',
  'description': '222',
  'id': '333',
  'others': '444',
};

$.each(values, function(key, value) {
  var elementId = $('#' + key + '_holder');
  elementId.length && elementId.is(':input') ? elementId.val(value) : elementId.text(value);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <span id="title_holder">###</span>
  <div id="description_holder">###</div>
  <input type="text" value="###" id="id_holder">
  <textarea id="others_holder">###</textarea>
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

First save default values to `data-reset`. On reset just restore values.
To check if element is input use `.is(':input')`

```js
var values = {
  'title': '111',
  'description': '222',
  'id': '333',
  'others': '444',
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.input').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':input')) {
      $(this).data('reset', $(this).text());
    }
  });

  $('[type="reset"]').click(function() {
    $('.input:not(:input)').each(function() {
      $(this).text($(this).data('reset'));
    });
  });


  $.each(values, function(key, value) {
    setVal($('#' + key + '_holder'), value);
  });
});


function setVal(el, value) {
  if (el.length > 0) {
    if (el.is(':input')) {
      el.val(value);
    } else {
      el.text(value);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <span id="title_holder" class="input">###</span>
  <div id="description_holder" class="input">###</div>
  <input type="text" value="###" id="id_holder" class="input">
  <textarea id="others_holder" class="input">###</textarea>
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for great solution for reset HTML elements, But as I said in the question this is not important for me. My answer is just `.is(':input')`

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of the input field. Depending on the type, use `val()` or `text()`

```
var elementType = elementId[0].tagName.toLowerCase();

if (elementType === 'input' || elementType === 'textarea') {
    elementId.val(value);
} else {
    elementId.text(value);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s13u699u/3/

Comment: This solution depends to `input` and `textarea` and not work for others input element of form.