# update textarea value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-wysihtml5

I'm using Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 html editor in my form like

```
 <input type="text" name="product" id="product">
 <textarea name="description" id="description" class="textarea" placeholder="Place some text here" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;">

 </textarea>
 <input type="product_code" name="product_code" id="product_code">
```

and using Ajax to fetch product details when product is entered in input field and want to update textarea with description

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($){
      $('#product').autocomplete({
        source:'<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "Products", "action" => "search")); ?>',
        minLength: 1
      });


      $('#product').blur(function() {
        var p_term = $(this).val();

        if (p_term) {
          var dataString = 'term='+ p_term;
          //alert(dataString);

          $.ajax({
              dataType:'json',
              type: "POST",
              url: '/products/ajax-search-product',
              data: dataString,
              cache: false,
              success: function(data) {

                /* set values to input field */
                $('#description').val(data['description']);
                $('#product_code').val(data['product_code']);

              },
              error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
              }
          });
        }
      });

    });
</script>
```

But this code is not updating values of textarea field while `$('#product_code').val(data['product_code']);` is working fine.

I tried to print value of textarea by `alert($('#description').val());` and it is working and printing prefilled value in textarea field.

> Edit 2

**Console output : `console.log(data);`**

```
Object { 
  id: 1, 
  product_code: "765457", 
  SKU: "", 
  title: "yuphoria screen guard", 
  description: "yuphoria screen guard", 
  short_description: "yuphoria screen guard", 
  15 more… 
}
```

I tried with this

```
$('#description').val(data['description']);    // this not working
alert(data['description']);                    // this working
```

There is only one `id="description"` and is nowhere else using.

Comment: It should work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854288/val-vs-text-for-textarea - any errors in console?

Comment: @mplungjan, he is using `val()` so I'm not sure how your link is relevant(?)

Comment: It is relevant to not have people answer "Use text()" as one immediately did

Comment: got it :) now with the "it should work" in your comment it is much clearer.

Comment: @Gaurav any chance you are doing some other manipulation to the `$('#description')` element somewhere in your code?

Comment: This works so there is no data returned in the ajax: `/* set values to input field */
                $('#description').val('description');
                $('#product_code').val('product_code');
` - my guess is empty or misspelled data['description']

Comment: @mplungjan, Its `val(data['description'])` and not `val('description')`. Anyway I tried with both but not working. `alert(data['description']);` works fine and value is printed it means it is not empty though.

Comment: @Dekel not using `('#description')` anywhere else.

Comment: My guess will be the same as @mplungjan suggested - you have some problem with the data returned from the server. Try using hardcoded values (`/* set values to input field */ $('#description').val('description'); $('#product_code').val('product_code'); `) to check where exactly your problem is.

Comment: I cannot test with data["description"] since I do not have your server available... What I am saying is that `<input type="text" name="product" id="product">
 <textarea name="description" id="description" class="textarea" placeholder="Place some text here" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;">

 </textarea>
 <input type="product_code" name="product_code" id="product_code"><script>$(function() {$('#description').val('description');})</script>` works so the error is in the data from the server. Console view the ajax

Comment: OR you have another id="description" on the page - you must have unique IDs

Comment: @mplungjan check my `Edit 2`

Comment: Please do `console.log($('#description').length); console.log($('#description'));`

Comment: this outputs `Object { length: 1, context: HTMLDocument → sell, selector: "#description", 1 more… }`

Comment: Pass...........................

Comment: sorry @mplungjan I didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, I hope it will help.

`$('iframe').contents().find('.wysihtml5-editor').html('your new content here');`

Comment: Please add a description to your it would be more helpful than just a piece of code