# Textarea .html() returns empty even if it has text on it

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form and some of the `<textarea>` values are coming filled by backend. When submitting I want to send inner HTML to the backend, when sending only the pre-filled are having values when calling their `.html()` but not `<textareas>` filled by the client. Any idea why this happens? I do the followings

I call this to get complete form html : `$('#myform').html();`
By calling this only pre-filled textarea is coming with the text in it like below

```
<teaxtarea name="t1" id="t1_001">The pre-filled text</textarea>
```

but for the text areas having text added from the client comes like this

```
<teaxtarea name="t2" id="t2_002"></textarea>
```

even if there is text added by the client.

Comment: You should actually put the code you have in here and then we can help. Otherwise, we have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Also, put in the HTML for the form.

Comment: Since `textarea` is an input field, you can try `val()` instead of `html()`.

Comment: Textareas usually have a `value`, rather than an `innerHTML`, so try `.val()`.

Comment: Yes you should use .val() to get textarea content,  there is difference between .html() & .val() for textarea see this link for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854288/val-vs-text-for-textarea

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer...

When I call this `$('#myform').html();` it does not take the textarea element with it's value rather the text enclosed by textarea tags. Since invoking .val() and .text() returns two separate values I called .text('value entered by client') when the user type on the textarea through a keypress event handler.
This fixed my problem.