# why is the textarea no longer updated after a manual modification?

Tags: jquery, textarea

the textarea updates correctly but no longer after manual modification !!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody').on("click", "td", function(a) {
    $("textarea").text($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<textarea rows='5' cols='33'></textarea>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Bulgarie</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cambodge</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CMC Chili</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Chine</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've created a snippet of your code, where it appears to work correctly. Can you provide a clearer description of exactly what you're trying to do and what the issue is

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Try click on a td, change the textbox and click again

Comment: You can use `$("textarea").val($(this).text());` to make it work

Comment: [val() vs. text() for textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854288/val-vs-text-for-textarea)

Comment: $("textarea").val($(this).text());
OR $("textarea").text($(this).text());
OR $("textarea").html($(this).text());


the code above does not work !!