# How to select empty inputs (value="") using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I check for empty values of (`required`) input fields within a section, and then add a class to them on an event, using jQuery? So far, I have tried:

```
jQuery("#sender_container input.required").val("").addClass("error");
```

But that seems to **SET** the value, rather than checking it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
jQuery("#sender_container input.required").filter(function() {
    return !this.value;
}).addClass("error");​
```

---

Why you have to use `filter` and not `[value=""]` you can see in [**this DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KGgaB/3)

The reason is: attribute selectors check the initial state of the element, not the current state. (note that you can change the "initial" state with the `attr` function, but it's bad practice, you should always use `prop`)

So if you change the input value, the current value won't effect the attribute selector. not wise... `:)`

Notes:

- `.val()` **returns** the value of the form element, and breaks the jQuery chain,
  `$('selector').val().addClass('foo')` **Error**, the return value is a string\ [**number**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9227268/601179)
- `.val(valueToSet)` **sets** the value of the form element and doesn't break the jQuery chain.
  `$('selector').val("some value").addClass('foo')` - **Valid**, the returned value is a jQuery

Comment: Thanks but this only works if ALL the inputs are empty. But if I have 2 required fields, and one has a value and the other is empty, nothing happens.

Comment: @RichardHarris. It should work fine in that case as well. there is something else in your code. see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KGgaB/1/)

Comment: @RichardHarris. [Or this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KGgaB/2/) used the css of codeparadox

Comment: Hmm. Trying to figure out why it doesn't work for me. Btw, your demo code is invalid because your div container closes immediately <div id="foo" />. Thanks for the help so far! Will update here when I can get it to work for me. Cheers!

Comment: @RichardHarris. Did you find what was the problem yet?

Comment: No, but after making some changes to other code in my scripts it worked. So it was something else, and not your code, that was the problem. Wish I knew exactly what it was.

Comment: [value=""] does not work, but [value=] does. This answer is much better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23321129

Comment: @gdoron You might want to check it yourself before assuming you were right and disregarding others' comments... Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/KGgaB/186/

Comment: @personne3000, my bad. Sorry. Curious to know if it's documented somewhere... Anyway, you're right, I was wring.

Comment: @personne3000, if it's not documented as officially supported, I would never use it as it looks a bit hacky. But if it does, that's a great way! Thank you for proving me wrong sir.

Comment: @gdoron Agreed about the documentation point; so I did some research to clear this up, and it turns out you are not actually wrong. jQuery < 1.9 (jsfiddle uses 1.7.2 for some reason) have inconsistent behavior with attribute selectors, which makes this hack work. jQuery 1.9+ works as you described; see the release notes for details on the change: https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop- ; jQuery 1.11+, 2.x and 3.x even throws a Syntax error, so the method I recommended previously is actually very wrong. I might edit your post to add this info.

Comment: @personne3000 thanks for the follow-up. Please do edit and add your findings.

Answer (score 11):

```
$('input:text[value=]','#sender_container').addClass('error');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NE4vu/1/)

Comment: This will not work in jQuery 1.9+, see https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#sender_container input.required[value=""]').addClass('error')
```

Comment: Actually it will not work at all, there is a wrong space between the input and the attribute selector... :) it will search for children of input with an empty value attribute, input can't have children...

Comment: Thanks, Parv. Your code should now work for any children of a containing element with id sender_container that is an input field using class required and whose value is empty, correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery('#sender_container input.required[value=""]').addClass("error");
```

You can try this:

```
$('input:not([value!=""])').addClass('error');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/5aFuY/3/)**

*Note:  This answer should not be used, and the only reason it wasn't deleted is so it can be learned from.*

Comment: either the inner or outer quotes need to be single, or escape the inner quotes.

Comment: @gdoron: Never mind, I tried it, it didn't work... strange, must have been something else then. But it definitely was related to the selectors and input field values ;)

Comment: @FelixKling Please check my demo

Comment: @FelixKling. That's weird, it looks like `:not[value...]` check the current state, $thecodeparadox, note that it's a bad selector to have.

Comment: I think he's saying it will assign class="error" to the value field, not the input element.

Comment: @gdoron if it is a bad selector how it works? I show the proof

Comment: @thecodeparadox. It's slower by 50%. [jsperf proof](http://jsperf.com/attribute-not-vs-filter). And the fact that it's weird it even works, is a **huge drawback**. I wouldn't use it, I hope neither do you. Good luck mate!

Comment: @gdoron: I think it's the `!=` and that's probably what I was referring to earlier, but could not properly remember. I assume, since `[attr!=value]` is not a CSS3 selector (afaik), it's evaluated by Sizzle and it seems to take the actual value. @thecodeparadox: Only because it works, does not mean it should be used. Double negations are difficult to understand as well.

Comment: @gdoron yup, will never use it. should I remove this post or keep here to make another aware

Comment: @thecodeparadox Leave the code, it's a good learning tool, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
$field = $("#sender_container input.required");
if( ! $field.val())
{
    $field.addClass("error");
}
```

this simple way may work.

Comment: $("#sender_container input.required").each(function( if( !   $(this).val())
{
    $(this).addClass("error");
})) try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to select based on the initial attribute value of the input then the following will do:

```
var elements = $('#sender_container input.required[value=""]')
```

But be aware that this won't work if the `value` attribute isn't present. It also won't work for the current input value if it has been changed by user or script.

If you'd like to get the current input value you can use *jquery*'s [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) function:

```
var elements = $('#sender_container input.required').filter(function() {
  return this.value === '';

  // alternatively for "no value":
  // return !this.value;
})
```

---

After you've selected the *jquery* elements you can add your class:

```
elements.addClass('error');
```

Answer (score 0):

to get all fields inspected this might help.

```
$('#sender_container [required]').each(function(index)
{
       if (!($(this).val())) $(this).addClass('error');
}

});
```