# How to find all drop downs which doesn't have any value selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which I submit manually (using JS) and it makes the querystring direct since it appends it with all the controls id (weather they have value or not) I read somewhere that I can avoid this by disabling the controls that have no values, before submitting the form.

Hence, In my form I have text box, checkbox and select (dropdowns), I am trying to write an inline query which will get all the select which have no option/values selected from its list :

This `$('form').find('select option:selected[value!=""]')` somewhat works but this `$('form').find('select option:selected[value=""]')` doesn't at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the overall issue that you don't want the form to be submitted using a GET (resulting in all the vars being in the query string)?  You can avoid this by using the POST method in your javascript instead.

Comment: A quick search reveals this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651349/how-to-select-empty-inputs-value-using-jquery - Now we just need to turn it around like this: `jQuery("select").filter(function(){return this.value;})`

Comment: @Twicetimes: Its a records filter page and the site functionality needs the user to be able to share the filtered results, hence used GET.

Comment: Ah ok, in that case I think @owenconti has the answer for the <select> elements

Comment: @somethinghere : this.value doesn't work on select types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward to do on form submission, by inspecting each element in the form. Make sure that you provide a way for users to actually re-enable the disabled form elements.

A working code would be:

```
$("#testForm").on("submit", function() {
    $(this).find('select option:selected[value=""]').parent().attr("disabled", "disabled");
    alert("ok");  // for debug purposes
    return false; // this stops the form from actually being submitted
});
```

Here's a working fiddle that demonstrates widget disabling:

http://jsfiddle.net/sw6v928m/3/

**Edit:** Updated to actually select disabled elements

**Edit 2:** Updated to compact the code a bit, after request from the OP

Comment: The example looks good, can this be done is single line as well ? no I guess ?

Comment: Wow this is beautiful, so I was missing .parent() yea ??

Comment: I'm not sure what you were missing, you never posted your complete source code :) But you want to target selected values, and disable the actual parent element that holds these values (which, in this case is the select list itself), in order to disable it

Comment: In the original question I mentioned that I tried $('form').find('select option:selected[value=""]'), anyhow thanks for pointing me to right direction.