# How to avoid specific inputs to be posted?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with several inputs. For some reason, I want specific inputs with specific class not be posted when the user submits the form.

I already tried disabling the specific inputs like:

```
$('.myinputs').each(function (i) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
});
```

This command would disable the inputs, but they still are being posted.

Any hints ?

Thanks

Comment: `disabled` actually prevent the inputs from submission, no need for formData IMO

Comment: You are doing right. `disabled` inputs will not be submitted. Only 1 thing I would to mention is that you need to put `(disabled',true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be disabled true not false, try :

```
$('.myinputs').each(function (i) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: While `'disabled'` will be cast to `true` when assigned to thh `disabled` property, you should use a boolean and not a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5904465/2660680)

You might need to put your logic onSubmit Event

```
$(function()
{
    $("form").submit(function()
    {
        $(this).children('.myinputs').attr("disabled", "disabled");

        return true; // ensure form still submits
    });
});
```