# $("input:not(:empty)") is not working

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    alert('hi'+$("input:text").val());
    $("input:not(:empty)").val("sdfdf");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" value="aa" />
<input type="text" value="" />
<input type="text" value="aa" />
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

i am trying to access empty textboxex using jquery and assigning a value hello to it..
but it's not working .

thanks in advance

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299424/selecting-empty-text-input-using-jquery

Answer (score 30):

[`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) checks for whether an element has child elements. `input` elements cannot have child elements.

If you want to test that the `input` element's value is blank:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("input").filter(function() {
        return this.value.length !== 0;
    }).val("sdfdf");
  });
});
```

There we get all of the `input` elements, and then filter it so only the ones whose `value` property isn't `""` are included.

Comment: This is the right way to do it. A selector like `input[type=text][value='']` probably isn't correct for this case because it only considers the initial value attribute and ignores characters entered by the user.

Answer (score 5):

You could use another selector for your task:

```
$("input[value='']").val("sdfdf");
```

Comment: Note that this selects based on the HTML attribute initial value; not the DOM property. Therefore if the user changes the value, this selector will not pick it up. [More on the difference between attributes and properties](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 4):

> jQuery(':empty')
>   Description: Select all elements that have no children (including text
>   nodes).

From http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/. Thus `:empty` does not do what you think it does.

Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1299468/138023 for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an .each with this inside:

```
if( $(this).val().length === 0 ) {
    $(this).parents('p').addClass('warning');
}
```