# jQuery attribute filter to get textbox based on a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get all empty text boxes on my page using jQuery. Somehow I am not able to get all the text boxes that are empty.

I have three text boxes like this

```
<input type="text" class="test" />
<input type="text" class="test" />
<input type="text" class="test" />

$(".test[value='']") -- this does not returns anything.
```

if i have this

```
<input type="text" class="test" value="a" />
<input type="text" class="test" />
<input type="text" class="test" />

$(".test[value='a']") -- this returns one control which is correct.
$(".test[value='']") -- this still returns nothing.
```

if I type "a" in the second textbox then
    $(".test[value='a']") -- this still returns only one control.

What wrong am I doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be searching where there is no `value` attribute, like this:

```
$('.test:not([value])')
```

or

```
$('.test'):not('[value]')
```

Based on your comments it seems that you want not to get the initial list of elements, but also be able to re-run the selector when someone inputs the value. The issue here is that if you enter the text to input, it does not add `value` attribute to the DOM. In this case you can use approach similar to what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1299468/3697011):

```
$('input:text').filter(function() { return this.value == ""; })
```

This approach checks the value of the input, not the DOM.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me up to some extent. Its getting the controls fine initially. If I type any text in one of the text boxes then this command still returns all the controls. I have created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rsetcma8/2/  . Click on Check after the page is loaded. It displays 3. Enter something in any of the textboxes and hit 'Check' again. It still displays 3.