# Hide an element on mouseup except when it has a content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have some elements that I want to hide once document body is clicked. This code came from an answer given in Stack Overflow:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
    var container = $(".time-stamp, .full-name, .comment-box-wrapper .search-result");
    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

It works fine but my page displays 10 different articles at a time and each article has textbox (`comment-box`) which are wrapped in `comment-box-wrapper` and attached to each articles where users can
submit their comments. These comment boxes are set to hidden by default until a user clicks on **Comment** button. The problem is if a user has
entered some text in the comment box and clicks elsewhere, the `comment-box` gets set to `hidden` and the content is lost completely.

How can I cancel `.hide()` if `comment-box` already has some content in it?

Comment: Add additional check in `if` to check `e.target.value.length `

Comment: Sorry, I was in a haste. The `comment-box` is wrapped in `comment-box-wrapper` that is set to hidden. Now I want to dig to `comment-box` and find out if it has content before setting `comment-box-wrapper` to hidden.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299424/selecting-empty-text-input-using-jquery

Comment: @UnLoCo: It didn't help me. I have done some edit on the question. Can you check it again?

Comment: Can you post your HTML it is a bit unclear what you want.

Comment: add this code `&& container.find('textarea').val().length == 0` to the `if` condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
    var container = $(".time-stamp, .full-name, .comment-box-wrapper.not-active .search-result");
    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});


$('.comment-box').on('change', function(){
    if(this.value!=""){
      $(this).parent().removeClass('not-active');
    }
})
```

Comment: In this case, I would have to add `.not-active` class to my textboxes?

Comment: well yes.. you need to add not-active classes to wrapper not textboxes