# Count <li> according to input type hidden that has value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I count the `li` according to each input type hidden that has value?

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="room_1">
    <li>
        <div class="wrap participantlist wrap_body" style="color:#000000">
           <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="1" id="channel">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="wrap participantlist wrap_body" style="color:#000000">
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="2" id="channel">
        </div>
     </li>
     <li>
        <div class="wrap participantlist wrap_body" style="color:#000000">
           <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="" id="channel">
        </div>
     </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
 var participantLength = $("#room_1 li").length;
 console.log(participantLength);
```

the number of input hidden that has value is 2

```
 <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="1" id="channel">
```

and

```
 <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="2" id="channel">
```

so the output should be `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there you go, it should show you the number of inputs those have value

```
$("ul li input[value!='']").length
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to all inputs like

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="2" id="channel" class="hidden_inputs">
```

than try

```
$('.hidden_inputs[value!=""]').length
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.each` function to iterate over the input element, and match if not empty values like so :

```
var inc = 0;
$('input:hidden').each(function(){
 if ( this.value !== "" )
    inc++; // increment by 1
 });
alert(inc); // get final output for input that not empty
```

Or just check at selector

```
alert($('input:hidden[value!=""]').length);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/ghg8dsab/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this one

```
 $('input:hidden[value!=""]').length
```

I noticed that you're using the same id(`id="channel"`) for the two inputs.
take note the ID should be unique, if you want to use the same name, use class instead*

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6e5Lnejn/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this

```
alert($("input[type='hidden'][value='']").length);
```

### [Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30whw3fp/)

Answer (score 1):

You can just just get that by:

```
alert($('input:hidden[value!=""]').length);
```

**for more info you can read this:**
[Selecting empty text input using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299424/selecting-empty-text-input-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can user `.filter()` for this:

```
 var inputs = $('input:hidden').filter(function(){
  return this.value !== "";
});
console.log(inputs.length);
```

you can find the live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rzt32nva/)